ERC-681 data field ignored by Metamask
Uri: ethereum:{address}?value=0&data=0x{hex}
Creating QR code from this to receive funds and scan with Metamask to send funds.
The problem is that data field is not included in the transaction, even I define in the uri. How to resolve this?
